# Open Office mail merge - pick text colour based on field value (formulas / scripting)?

Tags: formatting, field, formula, openoffice-writer, mailmerge

Is there a simple way (via formulas if possible rather than scripting) in Open Office text documents (.odt) to format characters via a formula based on the value of a mail-merge field?

The File -> New -> Label is great to create mail merge in OpenOffice, but how do I change the color of the text based on the value of one of the fields?

Example: one field is a country code. I would like FR to produce blue text, CA to produce red text, IE to produce green text...

More generalised: can I set a paragraph format based on the value of a field? For example I might want to left-align for a range of values, centre for others, right-align for yet another range.

Other than using macros, using LaTeX or whatnot, I'm just curious to hear if anybody out there has an easy answer with the mail-merge functionality in OpenOffice.